# How to format an int as currency in C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

I want to format an int as a currency in C#, but with no fractions.  For example, 100000 should be "$100,000", instead of "$100,000.00" (which 100000.ToString("C") gives).

I know I can do this with 100000.ToString("$#,0"), but that's $-specific.  Is there a way to do it with the currency ("C") formatter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use format "C0".

Comment: `.ToString("C0")` or `.ToString("C2")`... it only took me a second, but if it saves somebody a second....

Answer (score 2):

Possible to use n0 which provide commas like 1,234. Currency sign won't be there

Answer (score 1):

try

```
using System.Globalization
@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:c}", moneyvalue)
```

wil show the format in Rs.